# Java string array doesn't print correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on a Java program that crawls a webpage and prints out some information from it.

There is one part that I can't figure out, and thats when I try to print out one specific String Array with some information in it, all it gives me is " ] " for that line. However, a few lines before, I also try printing out another String array in the exact same way and it prints out fine. When I test what is actually being passed to the "categories" variable, its the correct information and can be printed out there.

```
public class Crawler {

private Document htmlDocument;
String [] keywords, categories;

public void printData(String urlToCrawl)
{
    nextURL=urlToCrawl;
    crawl();

    //This does what its supposed to do. (Print Statement 1)
    System.out.print("Keywords: ");
    for (String i :keywords) {System.out.print(i+", ");}

    //This doesnt. (Print Statement 2)
    System.out.print("Categories: ");
    for (String b :categories) {System.out.print(b+", ");}


}

public void crawl()
{
    //Gather Data

        //open up JSOUP for HTTP parsing.
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(nextURL).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
        Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
        this.htmlDocument=htmlDocument;

        System.out.println("Recieved Webpage "+ nextURL);


        int guacCounter = 0;
        for(Element guac : htmlDocument.select("script"))
        {
            if(guacCounter==5)
            {
                //String concentratedGuac = guac.toString();
                String[] items = guac.toString().split("\\n");
                categories = processGuac(items);
                break;
            }
            else if(guacCounter<5) {
                guacCounter++;
            }
        }
}
public String[] processKeywords(String totalKeywords)
{
    String [] separatedKeywords = totalKeywords.split(",");
    //System.out.println(separatedKeywords.toString());
    return separatedKeywords;
}

public String[] processGuac(String[] inputGuac)
{
    int categoryIsOnLine = 6;

    String categoryData = inputGuac[categoryIsOnLine-1];

    categoryData = categoryData.replace(",","");
    categoryData = categoryData.replace("'","");
    categoryData = categoryData.replace("|",",");
    categoryData = categoryData.split(":")[1];

    //this prints out the list of categories in string form.(Print Statement 3)
    System.out.println("Testing here: " + categoryData.toString());

    String [] categoryList=categoryData.split(",");

    //This prints out the list of categories in array form correctly.(Print statement 4)
    System.out.println("Testing here too: " );
    for(String a : categoryList) {System.out.println(a);}

    return categoryList;
}

}
```

I cut out a lot of the irrelevant parts of my code so there might be some missing variables.
Here is what my printouts look like:

PS1:

```
Keywords: What makes a good friend,  making friends,  signs of a good friend,  supporting friends,  conflict management,
```

PS2:

```
]
```

PS3:

```
Testing here:  wellbeing,friends-and-family,friendships
```

PS4:

```
Testing here too: 
 wellbeing
friends-and-family
friendships
```

Comment: Did you see what is coming inside categories array by debugging?

Comment: Since you are printing the string `Categories: `, it should be there in the output, somewhere, otherwise that `print()` statement never executed. FYI: You might want to do a `println()` before printing the label `Categories: `, otherwise it will be at the end of the line starting with `Keywords: `, or rather somewhere in the middle of that line.

Comment: @mubeen : The categories array is correct in both places where its mentioned.

Comment: @Andreas : When I did the debugging, "Categories: " was printed out, but when I stepped to the line where I was printing out the categories, the "Categories: " disappeared and was replaced with a " ] ", as shown above. However, "Categories: " only disappears when its on the same line as printing the categories array. When its one the line before, its fine.

Comment: @EricChan Then one of your category values contain a `CR` character, and a `]` character.

Comment: @Andreas Oh wow. There was a \r attached to the end of the last term. Thank you!

Comment: What are you splitting by as well, data is split by : then you split by , which you removed earlier.